# How to stop the header record being written twice with CsvWriter?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm in the process of upgrading an extremely large code base from CsvHelper V15.0.5 to V30.0.1.

The existing code base is quite complex, but has a function which is basically the equivalent of this:

```
async Task<string> WriteRecords(IEnumerable rows, Type t)
{
    using (var s = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var w = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(s), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true))
        {
            w.WriteHeader(t);
            await w.NextRecordAsync();
            await w.WriteRecordsAsync(rows);
        }
        
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(s.GetBuffer());
    }
}
```

The function can get called with the `rows` parameter set to an enumeration that may have 0, 1 or millions of rows. The function is supposed to write the rows if there are any and just write the header record if there are not. It was doing this fine, however after the upgrade it is writing the header row out twice in the event that the enumerator has any rows in it.

I tried removing the call to `WriteHeader(t)` but then the header is not written out when the `rows` parameter is an empty enumeration.

Is there some way to make `WriteRecordsAsync` not write out a header row ever, or is there a way to make it write the header row when `rows` is empty?

I can't seem to set `w.Configuration.HasHeaderRow` to `false` as it is read only. I also can't really set an attribute on all the classes that may get passed to this method as I don't really control that part of the application.

I'm aware I could do `if (rows.Any()) ...`, but I don't want to enumerate the thing twice for performance reasons.

Comment: Note: You can set the `HasHeaderRow` setting by creating the config file:  `var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) { HasHeaderRecord = false };` and passing that into your writer.

Comment: I'm having a hard time reproducing this issue. https://dotnetfiddle.net/BJxYPN a) if I have an empty entry list and `w.WriteHeader` is removed, the headers are still printed. b) Using the CsvConfiguration class mentioned by LarsTech and David Specht doesn't seem to impact the output.

Comment: @gunr2171 That is interesting.  The issue only gets reproduced when you put it into the `async Task` method. https://dotnetfiddle.net/1iTJvk

Answer (score 1):

##### CsvHelper Version 29.0.0

Passing `CsvConfiguration` with `HasHeaderRecord = false` appears to work.

```cs
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{ 
    HasHeaderRecord = false, 
    LeaveOpen = true 
};
using (var w = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(s), config))
```

##### CsvHelper Version 30.0.0

Starting with Version 30.0.0, `CsvWriter` appears to ignore the `HasHeaderRecord = false` configuration.  Current workaround would be to write out each row.

[CsvWriter.WriteRecords(IEnumerable records) ignores CsvConfiguration.HasHeaderRecords](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/2092)

```cs
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{ 
    HasHeaderRecord = false
};
using (var w = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(s), config, true))
{
    w.WriteHeader(t);
    await w.NextRecordAsync();
    
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        w.WriteRecord(row);
        await w.NextRecordAsync();
    }           
}
```